# Testing with Behave - cannot find modules

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-behave

I'm starting to write some BDD tests with Behave, but I'm having issues with trying to import my util modules in the tests.

Here is my current folder structure:

```
root/
    __init__.py
    README
    features/
        __init__.py
        test.feature
        environment.py
        steps/
            __init__.py
            steps_test.py
            utils/
              __init__.py
              string_utils.py
              user_utils.py
```

In my environment.py, I want some setup code to run before a feature:

```
import steps.utils.user_utils
def before_feature(context, feature):
    username = user_utils.create_username()
    print(username)
```

In my user_utils.py:

```
import string_utils
def create_username():
    name = string_utils.gen_str(10, 3)
    return name
```

But when I run `behave` from the project `root/` folder, I'm getting the error:

```
$ behave

...

File "root/features/steps/utils/user_utils.py", line 1, in <module>
    import string_utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'string_utils'
```

But if I run `python user_utils.py` inside the `utils/` folder, I don't get any errors, which indicates to me that it does find the module fine.

How can I get my module recognized with Behave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Behave is expecting a fairly strict directory structure. Namely, it does not search recursively through folders within the `steps/` folder. So, you need to move the contents of your `utils/` folder up into the `steps/` folder and it'll work fine.